# mysql optimize too many where conditions

Tags: mysql

the story: i have 2 tables of students. i need to find for every student in table A whether there is some student in table B that is younger and has the same name.

TABLE A (not real table, could be user input)

| id | name | age |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | jim | 12 |
| 1 | jack | 13 |
| 2 | tom | 23 |

TABLE B

| id | name | age |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | jim | 14 |
| 1 | jill | 10 |
| 2 | tim | 8 |
| 3 | jack | 12 |

this is my current sql query:

```
select * from table where name=jim and age<12 or name=jack and age<13 or ......
```

say i have to filter out the rows that match the input filter conditions（table A）, and the where keyword could be followed by 1000 more conditions combining name and age in pair. I tried this and could generate query using mybatis foreach, but the efficiency is very low. how to optimize the above query?

Comment: 1000 more conditions sounds brutal. please post what you are trying to do (not just the query but the logic)

Comment: Try to put the data that your are using in the filter in another table, and use that ...

Comment: say i have 2 tables of students. i need to find for every student in table A whether there is some student in table B that is younger and has the same name. this is what i have been trying to do.

Comment: Share a simple example. It could only have 5 students per table. and post desired output based on this data.

Comment: to me this looks pretty much the perfect example of a join. Share sample data, table structure and expected results

Comment: 'say i have 2 tables of students' - OK so why does the sample code only have 1? and what do you mean by same name - same last name , same first and last name?

Comment: Please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM StudentsA 
  JOIN StudentsB ON StudentsA.name = StudentsB.name
     WHERE StudentsA.age > StudentsB.age
```

If you define index on `(name,age)` Or `name` it will be faster and more performant!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT tableA.* 
  FROM tableA 
  INNER JOIN tableB ON tableA.name = tableB.name and tableA.age > tableB.age
```

see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/YNhD99u8)

You only need fixed comparsons when you need to find only studends that did not pass the age of 100  (`WHERE age<100`)

Using `tableA.name = tableB.name` will compare the name in tableA with the name in tableB